# Weird ping timeout on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ping

I have an weird issue with EC2 instance:

- I start a new Ubuntu instance (or any other).
- It initialize the instance and I can ping and connect via SSH, fine...
- Suddenly, I can't ping anymore! :(

**I have enabled all TCP, UDP and ICMP** (inbound and outbound) connections in the instance's Security Group. But no luck.

I also have tried connecting via SSH using Putty. No luck too.

I have searched a lot, but everyone says about the Security Group, which I already had configured to allow all traffic.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Prints :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UtE6.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Ou8.jpg

PS: I don't have reputation to post the images directly... :(

Comment: Does the instance continue, over time, to pass both of the health checks as shown in the console?

Comment: Yes, the checks are ok. Well, now it seems to be fine, I can ping. I tried to connect for almost an entire day before. Maybe, the problem was just wait for AWS to apply the configurations to the instance or the environment. Thanks for your reply @Michael-sqlbot!

Answer (score 1):

**I've just waited and now it seems to be ok.**

Maybe it was just a matter of time, wait for AWS to apply the configuration to the EC2 instance (I am using the South America region, São Paulo). But it drove me crazy because I took almost a entire day to try to connect to the instance.